# SSIS component failure does not work

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016, execute-sql-task

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and SQL Server 2016. 
I have a SSIS package and in that package I have a SQL Script Task that calls a simple script in which there is a error. 
I don't know why when there is a error , the flow does not go throw `Failure` path.

This is part of my package where I have Failure path.

[image]

This is my sql code :

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, N'aa1') AS Status
```

This is my error :

```
    [Execute SQL Task] Error: 
            Executing the query "SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, N'aa1') AS Status
            ..." failed with the following error: 
            "Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.". 
            Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, 
            "ResultSet" property not set correctly, 
             parameters not set correctly,
             or connection not established correctly.
```

Why my task failed dispute my failure path?

[image]

Comment: With the query you provide, I created a simple package with 2 task, and the failure path is executed. Can you show us what is the task linked in the failure path ?

Comment: @EzLo Dose not work. I have put "MAximumErrorCount" to 10000 but still `Execute sql task` has error

Comment: It is normal that the task has an error because the query throw an error. The failure path is just a path to go when the task is in error it doesnt prevent error to append. Look again at my updated answer to the schema of error/success tasks.

Comment: @Kobi Thanks. It worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the link you made between task, plain line signify `AND`.
 So the move_file_to_fatal_error cannot be executed since it is waiting both success and error path to realize.

You should edit the two link between task and FST_Move and select `Logical OR`

[image]

Comment: What you told is correct but i have error in first step. I modified my question to explain more simple.